# Parent child relation in C# classes

Tags: c#

I have the following case:

```
public class ParentObject
{
public int id {get;set;}
public string parent_object_name {get;set;}
public List<ChildObject> child_objects {get;set;}
}

public class ChildObject
{
public int id {get;set;}
public string child_object_name {get;set;}
}

ParentObject parent_object = new ParentObject()
{
  id = 1,
  parent_object_name = "test name",
  child_objects = new List<ChildObject>(){ new ChildObject(){ id = 1, child_object_name = "test name"};
}
```

I am aware that it is perfectly valid to reference `parent_object.child_objects`, but I am not sure how can I code my classes to have a reference such as `child_objects.First().parent_object` ie. similar to navigational properties in Entity Framework.

Comment: @Fildor edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to define a constructor that accepts the parent as parameter.

```
public class ChildObject
{
  public ChildObject(ParentObject aParent)
  {
    parent = aParent
  }

  public ParentObject parent { get; private set; }
  public int id {get;set;}
  public string child_object_name {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
public class ChildObject
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string child_object_name { get; set; }
    public ParentObject parent_object { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Would it be advisable to use a WeakReference?

Comment: @Fildor - Why? For what purpose? You think that the parent might be GCed but the child shouldn't be?

Comment: That was my thought, yes. But I am not sure if it's necessary. Now that I read your comment it may even be a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

By adding a `ParentObject` in `ChildObject`, you can use the parent from the child:

[Try it online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hZifmp)

```
public class ParentObject
{
    public int id {get;set;}
    public string parent_object_name {get;set;}
    public List<ChildObject> child_objects {get;set;}
}

public class ChildObject
{
    public int id {get;set;}
    public string child_object_name {get;set;}

    // add a parent
    public ParentObject parent_object {get;set;}
}


public static void Main()
{
    var parent_object = new ParentObject
    {
        id = 1,
        parent_object_name = "test name"
    };
    parent_object.child_objects = new List<ChildObject>
    {
        new ChildObject {id = 1, child_object_name = "test name", parent_object = parent_object}
    };
    Console.WriteLine(parent_object.child_objects.First().parent_object.parent_object_name);
}
```